# SQL Query is good, but get error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
function GetSetting($key)
{
    $Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE keys='$key'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {
        return $Row['value'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys='header_title'' at line 1

What is wrong with my SQL query?

Comment: Query is good but you have a santax error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`keys` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so you'll have to escape it:

```
SELECT ... WHERE `keys`='$key';
                 ^----^--
```

In other words, your query actually isn't good, and MySQL was telling you exactly where the problem was...